# Writing like an Arbitrator or Mediator - How would I search for that?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, learning

User Jasper's instructive comment under [How to phrase a follow-up question politely, if there's evasion?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31079/8712) motivated this question:

> Dale Carnegie's *How to Win Friends and Influence People* addresses many similar topics. (Unfortunately, I don't think it addresses this exact topic.) The best editions of the book were published before he died in 1955.

I was wondering if there other reputable books or references on the subject of writing politely or cordially, but with conviction and effect.

**What's this subject or practice or method called, so that I can try searching?**

Comment: According to the [help/on-topic], requests for resources are out of scope for this site. However, asking what it's called seems like a fair question.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.brunerbiz.com/2009/04/giving-feedback-diplomatically/) in Google under "writing **diplomatically**."

I found [this](http://www.englishbiz.co.uk/mainguides/argue.htm) under "writing **tactfully and effectively**."

I would recommend you conduct your own searches with these terms and see what comes up.